# Проверка возвратил ли что-то SQLite select

Tags: java, sqlite

как я могу проверить, вернул ли что-то данный запрос?
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE NICK ='" + nick + 
    "';" );
(Я хочу проверить имеется ли запись с данным никнеймом в таблице)

Comment: используйте next() в цикле, `while(rs.next())`, и далее вызывайте методы вида rs.getXXX(n), где XXX - тип данных в столбце, 
n - номер столбца

Comment: Учитывая разнобой в ответах, уточните, пожалуйста, что именно вам нужно сделать: просто узнать наличие записи, получить информацию (одну строку) или вообще вам нужно вставить новую запись, если такой еще нет?

Comment: И уточните платформу: может Android? И доступ к БД осуществляет один клиент или многие?

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```
int q=0;
while (rset.next()) {
    q++;
}
```

или так

```
int count = -1;
if ( resultSet.last() ) {
   count = resultSet.getRow();
}
```

Comment: Избыточно делать запрос на все записи с таким логином,чтобы посчитать количество таких же логинов,не правда-ли?

Comment: Согласен, но вопрос был как проверить вернул ли что-то данный запрос... С какой целью автору нужна информация об имеющемся пользователе из вопроса не совсем понятно, может нужна дополнительная информация если пользователь найден.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, используйте [параметризованные](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) запросы.

Во-вторых, можно использовать методы [isBeforeFirst()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isBeforeFirst()) или [first()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#first()):

```
if (!resultSet.isBeforeFirst()) // no rows

if (!resultSet.first()) // no rows
```

В-третьих, если вам действительно нужно лишь проверить, существует ли данный никнейм в таблице, то не нужно вытягивать всю информацию о нём: `select *`, - достаточно одного поля: например, `select id`. Ещё лучше будет использовать запрос, вообще не возвращающий строки из БД, а только булево значение: есть или нет такой пользователь. Используйте для этого `exists` или `count` в sql-запросе.

---

<sub>Хотел было я дать ссылки на so-ответы по третьему пункту, но там сплошь склеивание строк для sql-запросов, вытягивание всей таблицы целиком на клиент и тому подобный ужас. И это заплюсованные ответы! Понятно, почему столько багов и тормозов в нынешнем софте... Мда, моя вера в программинг сильно пошатнулась.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите проверить существует ли запись в таблице самым удобным и простым способом будет исльльзовать `EXISTS`. Примерное решение:

```
private static final int FIRST_ROW = 1;
...
public boolean isUserExist(String userName){
    String userQuery = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE NICK = " + userName + " LIMIT 1)";

    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(userQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    boolean isRecordExist = cursor.getInt(FIRST_ROW) == 1;
    cursor.close();
    return isRecordExist;
}
```

`EXISTS` возвращает 1 если подобный никнейм уже существует и 0 если нет. В коде могут быть ошибки, набрал по памяти в блокноте.

Comment: тега android в вопросе нет, а решение специфичное только для платформы android

Comment: @pavlofff, перечитайте мой ответ и поймете что я акцентировал внимание на использовании EXISTS, а код примерный и я это указал.

Answer (score 0):

Наверно,вы делаете регистрацию и делаете проверку на занятость логина.
Я проверял условие имеется ли такой логин в таблице следующим образом.Он не избыточный,как по мне.

```
public boolean login_is_busy(String login) {
    try {
        stat = connection.createStatement();
        result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT count(login) FROM `users` WHERE 
        login='"+login+"';");

        result.next();
        int count = result.getInt(1);
            if(count == 0) {
                return false;
        // Таких логинов нету,значит мы возвращаем false,что значит не занятый
            }
    }catch(SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Записи с таким логином есть,значит true ибо он занят
    return true;
}
```

Этот запрос возвращает один столбец с числовым значением(Количество записей с таким логином)
Далее,можно сделать такую штуку:

```
public void method(String login){

 if(login_is_busy(login)){
    // Говорите,что логин занят
 }
 if(!login_is_busy(login)){
   // Говорите,что логин свободный
 }
 //...
```

Таким образом,вы чуть-чуть убрали возможный говнокод,если бы писали всю логику в одном методе.